# How to enable winhlp on Windows7 64bit?

Tags: windows-7

Salvete!  I just discovered that winhlp32.exe won't run on Windows7 64bit.  I can't run the application, and I can't run hlp files either (but .chm files run fine).  How do I make this work?

I have downloaded the Microsoft fix [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917607) and restarted my computer, but to no avail.  I can see the file `winhlp32.exe` `in my c:\windows` directory, but cannot run it.  When I do run it, I get Windows' own "Help and Support" entitled, "Why can't I get Help from this program?" which sends me to the link above!

How can I make it work?

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: Sorry - I should have said that.  I just added it to the question.

Comment: You installed the x64 version of this hotfix correct? Trying to make sure you installed Windows6.1-KB917607-x64.msu

Comment: Whoops - I installed the wrong package: Windows6.1-KB958559-x64-RefreshPkg.msu  - you got me on that one.  Solved.  Please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it accepted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you attempted to install the 32-bit version of this hotfix.

If you do indeed want to install this hotfix.  You need to install 64-bit **Windows6.1-KB917607-x64.msu** version instead instead of the 32-bit version (**Windows6.1-KB917607-x86.msu**).

Comment: The 32-bit version was usable with Windows 8, after updating to 8.1, WinHlp32 "silently" gave up working. This fixed it for me :-) I hope the upgrade to Windows 10 will not break it again.